# Efficient multiplication of large arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, namely, `New` with `shape = (5100,)` and `A` with `shape = (5100, 5100)`. I am multiplying these two arrays and measuring the time taken to perform this operation. The time turns out to be `0.409 seconds`. Is there a more time efficient way to multiply such large arrays?

```
Pe=A*New
```

Comment: This takes 0.08 seconds on my PC

Comment: Is there even a faster way to perform this operation?

Comment: How did you time it? You may be measuring the cost of getting your time values. After `from timeit import timeit` you could  do `print(timeit("a1*a2", setup="import numpy as np;a1,a2=np.ones(shape=(5100,)),np.ones(shape=(5100,5100))", number=100)/100)`.

Comment: @RFeynman123 Not that I know of, that operation is *highly* optimized using BLAS/LAPACK

Comment: Assuming these are integers or floats, this is a pretty fast way. There is python level setup and teardown for the multiply, but then the operation itself is done in a C level loop and is fast. This is about as good as it'll get for python.

Comment: If your matrices are sparse (mostly zero) then you can use scipy's sparse matrices, which will be much faster.

Comment: Specify the type and dtype of the arrays, and how you are doing this multiplication.

Comment: The answer is : yes, probably. But if you want a more complete answer, then you should give much more details about the context and your needs (ie. a more complete question). For example, is it used in a loop ? Is it OK to overwrite the inputs ? What is your target processor and RAM ? What is the datatype of the arrays. Etc.

Comment: @TomMcLean No, Numpy does not use BLAS for this element-wise array multiplication. It is used for level 2/3 BLAS (eg. matrix multiplication). Level 1 BLAS are not so useful nowadays except for convenience.